# glCreateProgram().uniform in python

Tags: python, opengl, shader, pyopengl

I am trying to port some javascript code with opengl to python. But cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in translating `prog.uniform[u] = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, u);`

Javascript:

```
let v = buildShader(vert, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
let f = buildShader(frag, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
let prog = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(prog, v);
gl.attachShader(prog, f);
gl.linkProgram(prog);
prog.uniform = {};
u = ['model','bounds','frac','aspect'];
_.each(u, function(u){ prog.uniform[u] = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, u); });
```

Python3/PyOpenGl:

```
v = self.buildShader(vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
f = self.buildShader(frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
prog = glCreateProgram()
glAttachShader(prog, v)
glAttachShader(prog, f)
glLinkProgram(prog)
for u in ['model','bounds','frac','aspect']:
  loc = glGetUniformLocations(prog,u)
  glProgramUniform(prog,loc,u)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`glProgramUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glProgramUniform.xhtml) assigns a value to a uniform, where the 3rd paramter is the value.

`glProgramUniform(prog,loc,u)` makes not any sense, when `u` is string which is the name name of the uniform.

You have to create a dictionary which contains the locations of a uniform for each name:

```
uniform = {}
for u in ['model','bounds','frac','aspect']:
    uniform[u] = glGetUniformLocation(prog, u)
```

or simply

```
uniform = { u : glGetUniformLocation(prog, u) for u in ['model','bounds','frac','aspect'] }
```

Comment: Thx, how to port the `prog.uniform[u]=` part to python3?

Comment: @Nard No way, because in python `prog` is t name of the shader program object, which is just a number. You have to create a tuple `(prog, uniform)`.

Comment: Stupid question probably, but then how do I  pass the `uniform`-variable to opengl or is this not what is happening in the js-code `prog.uniform[u] =` ?

Comment: @Nard No `prog.uniform[u]` doesn't assign anything to uniform variable on the GPU in WebGL (not OpenGL). This is done by  [`gl.Uniform`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/uniform)